# How do I detect corrupt files?

Tags: search, file-corruption

I have many files, MP4, Mp3, Exe and others, which during a backup did not correctly copy to the hard drive for whatever reason, I have checked the file contents with a hex editor to find that many of the corrupt files have 00 filled areas where there is supposed to be data, and some of them have random data where there is supposed to be functional data. At least for the 00 filled files, there should be a way to search for all of these and locate them. I've tried the windows Search tool (Windows 8.1) and enabled file contents searching, however, as there is no way to search Hex in windows search I searched for the ASCII ..... period which represents 00 Hex. I copied the correct .... from the hex editor and paste it into search, it didn't work.

I would like to find all files which have a large quantity of 00 hex fill but do not know how to do this, any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Binary Viewer](https://www.proxoft.com/BinaryViewer.aspx) program has a function that will allow you to search for Hex sequences and binary patterns within given directories (or you can specify root for your entire machine).

One other possible solution is to programmatically scan through all your files and pick out those with a higher than expected number of "00" values (i.e. those with a large mean number of "00"'s).  You'll want to use a programming language for this.  Since I'm a statistician, I like the `R` programming language because:

1. It's free; and
2. It's relatively easy to learn.

In `R`, you can examine the "hex" values of a file (I'm assuming you are looking at the 1 Byte hexes here) with the following `R` code:

```
install.packages("DescTools")
library(DescTools)
myBinary="D:/temp/2.jpg"

myhex = readRaw(myBinary)
#View first 20 entries
head(myhex$fileRaw, n=20)
 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00
```

Now you can find the mean number of "00" entries:

```
#Find the mean number of times a "00" entry appears in this file
mean(myhex$fileRaw=="00")
 0.008298835
```

All you'd need to do is put a simple looping structure around this code to loop through all the files in a directory and output the mean number of "00" entries.  You could get even more sophisticated and "train" the optimal naive mean cutoff point by running this algorithm through a bunch of **known** good (i.e. uncorrupt) files and computing the average mean of "00" entries in the files there (i.e. the mean of means).  You could probably compute a typical confidence interval around this and likely use an upper end of the confidence interval as the cutoff point to feed into your program to search for files of **unknown** corruption.  This would help you to pick off those that corrupt.

Comment: @Corky, an up-vote and/or selecting the check mark to the left of my my answer text is the accepted way on Super-User to accept an answer.  Would you mind doing this to encourage others to provide answers?  Glad I could help in this instance!